# Opencl clWaitEvent() after clFinish() cause memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, opencl

I have some problem of memory leak due to the function clWaitEvent().
I use clWaitEvent() for compute the execution time of my kernel :

```c++
ciErrNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(this->commandQueue, this-> kernel_calcHash, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, &localWorkSize, 0, NULL, &prof_event);

clFinish(this->commandQueue);
ciErrNum = clWaitForEvents(1, &prof_event);
ciErrNum |= clGetEventProfilingInfo(prof_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &ev_start_time, NULL);
ciErrNum |= clGetEventProfilingInfo(prof_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &ev_end_time, NULL);
ciErrNum |= clReleaseEvent(prof_event);
oclCheckError(ciErrNum, CL_SUCCESS);
```

with valgrind, i find some memory leak which its remove if I comment the clWaitForEvents() function.
I release the event after this method, so I don't know why, this happen. Anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Could be a poor OpenCL implementation

Comment: do you mean, the openCL version ?

the profil of the platform I choose is :
PROFILE = FULL_PROFILE
  VERSION = OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 6.5.14
  NAME = NVIDIA CUDA
  VENDOR = NVIDIA Corporation
  EXTENSIONS = cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll 

and for my device is :
DEVICE_NAME = GeForce GTX 690
  DEVICE_VENDOR = NVIDIA Corporation
  DEVICE_VERSION = OpenCL 1.1 CUDA
  DRIVER_VERSION = 340.29

so it is opencl 1.1 version

Comment: I mean that the memory leak could be inside of the OpenCL library. OpenCL objects are reference counted and are freed if the counter is down to 0. With clReleaseEvent you decrement the counter by 1 and since you don't increment it in your (provided) code the event should be freed. It isn't so it could be a problem inside the OpenCL implementation from Nvidia.

Comment: I don't think there are an error inside the OpenCL library for this issue, because, I don't find this wuestion in the web. So I thinks I do a mistake. Can you explain me, when the counter is increment ?
The only moment I use the event, it in the code I post.

Comment: You shouldn't need clWaitForEvents in this example. You only really need either clFinish or clWaitForEvents. Either should make sure the profiling info is ready. I don't see a reason for your code to have a memory leak, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this afer clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

```
clFinish(CommandQueue);
```